# Run time error while using Simple Edge Detection Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, opencv

I am using a simple edge detection package in a flutter.
https://github.com/flutter-clutter/flutter-simple-edge-detection

I got this run time error while using the process image function.

```
E/cv::error()(25743): OpenCV(4.4.0) Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 396761445280 bytes) in OutOfMemoryError, file /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp, line 73
E/libc++abi(25743): terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.4.0) /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 396761445280 bytes in function 'OutOfMemoryError'
F/libc (25743): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 26135 (DartWorker), pid 25743 (_app_docscanner)

Build fingerprint: 'Xiaomi/riva/riva:8.1.0/OPM1.171019.026/V11.0.2.0.OCKMIXM:user/release-keys'
Revision: '0'
ABI: 'arm64'
pid: 25743, tid: 26135, name: DartWorker >>> com.dev.flutter_app_docscanner <<<
signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
Abort message: 'terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: OpenCV(4.4.0) /build/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/alloc.cpp:73: error: (-4:Insufficient memory) Failed to allocate 396761445280 bytes in function 'OutOfMemoryError'
'
x0 0000000000000000 x1 0000000000006617 x2 0000000000000006 x3 0000000000000008
x4 fefefefefefeffee x5 fefefefefefeffee x6 fefefefefefeffee x7 7f7f7f7f7f7f7fff
x8 0000000000000083 x9 d8990fa8bbd15576 x10 0000000000000000 x11 0000000000000001
x12 ffffffffffffffff x13 000000005f9804cc x14 00135f14cf2c6400 x15 00009bbecf145629
x16 0000005d0d39dfa8 x17 00000073d84ee598 x18 00000073336dad84 x19 000000000000648f
x20 0000000000006617 x21 00000073298fdb68 x22 ffffff80ffffffc8 x23 00000073298fdc20
x24 00000073298fdb00 x25 00000073298fdb40 x26 0000007337858400 x27 000000732f33fb30
x28 0000000000000004 x29 00000073298fda70 x30 00000073d84a3df8
sp 00000073298fda30 pc 00000073d84a3e14 pstate 0000000060000000
backtrace:
#00 pc 000000000001de14 /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+104)
#1 pc 000000000009ce88 /data/app/com.dev.flutter_app_docscanner-IsHbl2638h0fBP3Q2TWjlQ==/lib/arm64/libc++_shared.so
#2 pc 000000000009d07c /data/app/com.dev.flutter_app_docscanner-IsHbl2638h0fBP3Q2TWjlQ==/lib/arm64/libc++_shared.so
#3 pc 00000000000aead0 /data/app/com.dev.flutter_app_docscanner-IsHbl2638h0fBP3Q2TWjlQ==/lib/arm64/libc++_shared.so
#4 pc 00000000000ae3d8 /data/app/com.dev.flutter_app_docscanner-IsHbl2638h0fBP3Q2TWjlQ==/lib/arm64/libc++_shared.so (__cxa_rethrow+196)
#5 pc 0000000000305174 /data/app/com.dev.flutter_app_docscanner-IsHbl2638h0fBP3Q2TWjlQ==/lib/arm64/libopencv_java4.so (cv::Mat::create(int, int const*, int)+1316)
#6 pc 0000000000327d98 /data/app/com.dev.flutter_app_docscanner-IsHbl2638h0fBP3Q2TWjlQ==/lib/arm64/libopencv_java4.so
#7 pc 000000000001ce64 /data/app/com.dev.flutter_app_docscanner-IsHbl2638h0fBP3Q2TWjlQ==/lib/arm64/libnative_edge_detection.so (_ZNK2cv7MatExprcvNS_3MatEEv+96)
#8 pc 000000000001c9fc /data/app/com.dev.flutter_app_docscanner-IsHbl2638h0fBP3Q2TWjlQ==/lib/arm64/libnative_edge_detection.so (ImageProcessor::crop_and_transform(cv::Mat, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float)+512)
#9 pc 000000000001c788 /data/app/com.dev.flutter_app_docscanner-IsHbl2638h0fBP3Q2TWjlQ==/lib/arm64/libnative_edge_detection.so (ImageProcessor::process_image(cv::Mat, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float)+136)
#10 pc 000000000000ef6c /data/app/com.dev.flutter_app_docscanner-IsHbl2638h0fBP3Q2TWjlQ==/lib/arm64/libnative_edge_detection.so (process_image+640)
#11 pc 00000000000065a4 anonymous:000000733b480000
Lost connection to device.
```

Comment: I tried same image in the example app but it worked.

Comment: Does the image in the example app have a lower resolution than the one you're testing?

Comment: Ok got the solution after reading your comment. The change was in resolution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Out of Memory** is pretty clear that you are using an image whose resolution is beyond the capabilities of what your device can handle.

You'll need to scale your input image so that's it's smaller. There's an example image that is accompanied with this code. Try scaling your image down to the same size as the example image.